# Uncheck to checkbox affecting value of user control in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have four user control. which I have added in main window like this:

```
AbstractObject obj = ObjectFactory.CreateObject(Protocol.CP, 2);
AbstractObject obj1 = ObjectFactory.CreateObject(Protocol.CP, 2);


private List<ChannelRSUserControl> channelRsUserControl = new List<ChannelRSUserControl>();

this.channelRsUserControl.Add(new ChannelRSUserControl(obj, 0));-----> user control1
this.channelRsUserControl.Add(new ChannelRSUserControl(obj, 1));------> user control2

this.channelRsUserControl.Add(new ChannelRSUserControl(obj1, 0));------> user control3
this.channelRsUserControl.Add(new ChannelRSUserControl(obj1, 1)); ------> user control4

this.mainWindow.grid1_ChannelData.Children.Add(this.channelRsUserControl[0]);
this.mainWindow.grid2_ChannelData.Children.Add(this.channelRsUserControl[1]);

this.mainWindow.grid3_ChannelData.Children.Add(this.channelRsUserControl[2]);
this.mainWindow.grid4_ChannelData.Children.Add(this.channelRsUserControl[3]);
```

this user control has text box and slider control. and Main window has this user control and checkbox.

As you can see I have created two object obj and obj1 for my user control.

When I'm launching my application on that My checkbox by default is checked and all four user control is behaving ok.

I mean If I move slider control from user control1 ,It's not affecting other user control at all.

Suppose I have move my slider control like this :

user control1 ----> slider control has value 20

user control2----> slider control has value 40

user control3 ----> slider control has value 60

user control4 ----> slider control has value 80

Once I do uncheck to check box then user control1 and user control3 has same value like 20 and user control2 and user control4 has same value like 40.

Which is wrong . What I want that no user control will affect any user control value when I'm doing uncheck to check box.

check and uncheck to check box used only for changing mode from real mode to set mode.

See the below discription:

1. For object obj I have two index 0 ,1 and for each index I have One user control object 
   e.g for index 0 with object obj new ChannelRSUserControl(obj, 0) and same way for index 1 with object obj new ChannelRSUserControl(obj, 1)

same way for object obj1 have also index 0 ,1 and each index have user control object.

During check box checked and unchecked performing the following operation:

```
Binding rsBind = BindingOperations.GetBinding(this.control.sliderrs,    Slider.ValueProperty);
Binding rsBindnew = new Binding("Rs");
rso2Bindnew.Path = rso2Bind.Path;
UpdateSourceTrigger value = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

 value = (e.OperatingMode == ModeOfOperation.REAL) ? 
 UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged : UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit;
 operatingMode = e.OperatingMode;
 rso2Bindnew.UpdateSourceTrigger = value;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.control.sliderrs, Slider.ValueProperty, rsBindnew);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.control.tbrs, TextBox.TextProperty, rstbBind);
```

P.S: Rs is property which I have bind to slider control and slider control is bind to text box.

Hope I'm very clear now. Please respond so that I can solve this issue.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What action you perform when check/uncheck??

Comment: could you please post a sample working code, so we can answer you quickly. seems like many bits are missing in your description.

Comment: You're trying to use WPF as if it were Windows Forms... it is *far* from Windows Forms, so your code is far from optimal. You need to learn to use XAML.